# MySql count using and still show all data even using where clause

Tags: mysql, count, data

Good Afternoon,

How i can show all data when using count and where clause in MySql.
In my case, I have master data like pict at below.

[image: Master Data]

and i using this query to show count the data.

```
SELECT body,
       count(body) 
from tb_list_data 
WHERE type ="FAC" 
AND  group by body 
order by body ASC
```

and then the result like pict at below

[image: result from the query]

But i want the query result like pict in below.

[image]

how i do query to still show all data like that pict even using clause where?

Thank You.

Comment: Please for other questions consider using text instead of image as I have shown in my answer

Comment: Please consider [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530) - images are a "bad thing" (TM)! I can't see them on the bus!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `WHERE type ="FAC"`  you are limiting yourself only on the body values where type equal FAC. By the way you have an additional AND , but I'm guessing it should be a typo.

You need to use a case condition .

Consider the following data ,

```
create table tb_list_data (
  type  varchar(10),
  body  varchar(10) );

insert into tb_list_data values 
('FAC','Hand'),('FAC','Head'),('MTC','Feet'),('MTC','Finger'),
('FAC','Hand'),('FAC','Head'),('FAC','Legs');
```

---

```
select body,
       count(case when type = 'FAC' then 1 end) as cnt
from tb_list_data
group by body
order by cnt asc  ;
```

Or written differently

```
select body,
       SUM(type = 'FAC') as cnt
from tb_list_data
group by body
order by cnt asc  ;
```

In both cases result would be

```
body    cnt
Feet     0
Finger   0
Legs     1
Hand     2
Head     2
```

[See example](https://dbfiddle.uk/dV3bpBj0)

Comment: Hi Ergest Basha,

oh Great, thank you so much. work nicely.